# What kind of accommodation does "homestay" actually refer to in Malaysia?

Tags: accommodation, terminology, malaysia, homestay

Anywhere else in the world as far as I know, "homestay" means a kind of accommodation where you live with a local family in their home, so maybe a bit like a guesthouse but more personal and intended to give you an insight into the local culture and lifestyle.

But in Malaysia, at least on the east coast, the places with "homestay" signs looked more like what I would call motels or sometimes bungalows. They didn't look like people's homes and often had a parking space outside each room or cabin.

I didn't stay in any and I've now crossed the border. I don't remember seeing any on the west side of Malaysia, but I wasn't looking. Before I travelled on the east coast myself, a fellow traveller I met had told me that while he was on the east coast he enquired at several homestays and was surprised that they were expensive compared to homestays he'd used in other countries, and didn't seem to be the same thing.

I also can't recall seeing any signs saying "motel" so maybe this is the misnamed equivalent. I did stay in two places that called themselves "resorts" but to me felt more like what I would also consider to be motels or bungalows.

So in the Malaysian context, what kind of kinds of accommodation does "homestay" generally refer to? How do they differ from homestays elsewhere, and how do they compare to the concept of motels and bungalows elsewhere and to resorts in Malaysia?

Comment: I don't know about the specific situation in Malaysia, but if I would guess, it is a literal translation of 民宿/Minshuku that originally refers to bed&breakfast kind of accom. where you share the building with the property owner in the spare rooms. However, it may have become genericized as a new name to designate any kind of accommodation with some (or none of) "local flavour" like the use of 民宿 in China (where nowadays 民宿 could be a (air)B&B, budget hotel/hostel or even luxury resort or anything other than chain or "classic" hotels).

Comment: Can't remember if I stayed at Minshuku but I stayed at a place in Bulgaria with a "minbak" sign in Korean! That was with hosts, as expected. I stayed in guesthouses in a few countries including JB, Malaysia, which were where the hosts lived. I remember homestays in Laos where you ate with the family but didn't use any. They have AirB&B here but I haven't used one. I don't recall seeing jut B&B here. "Resorts" I stayed at here were not luxury though one may have been a bit fancy when it was new. Googling suggests there should be "normal" homestays here too - maybe the meaning shifted?